# $.Mustache.load and $.Mustache.render

Tags: javascript, html, mustache, jquery-templates

i have next question. I have this code for loading my templates:

```
$.Mustache.load( "./templates/news/home.tpl" );
```

Which is:

```
function load(url, onComplete)
{
    return $.ajax({
            url: url,
            dataType: options.externalTemplateDataType
    }).done(function (templates)
    {
        $(templates).filter('script').each(function (i, el)
        {
                add(el.id, $(el).html());
            });

            if ($.isFunction(onComplete)) {

                onComplete();
            }
    });
}
```

And when i make a click, to get to the other page:

```
$("body").append($.Mustache.render(pageId + "-template", data));
```

Which is:

```
function render(templateName, templateData) {
    alert(!has(templateName));
    if (!has(templateName)) {

        if (options.warnOnMissingTemplates) {
            $.error('No template registered for: ' + templateName);
        }
        return '';
    }
    return getMustache().to_html(templateMap[templateName], templateData, templateMap);
}
```

So my it falls at :   if (!has(templateName)) because sais that template is not loaded, what is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Templates weren't loading because i have to set full path - www/templates/news/home.tpl
Sometimes there is a lag, and WP doesn't load templates with *.tpl format, so i changed it to txt and all worked

Answer (score 1):

Why don't You use *.html extension? And editors will recognize it as HTML syntax too. :)